# How to download Django 1.6.2 + set the path to python3?

Tags: python3, django

I don't know how to set the path.

1. How shall I install  django?
2. How do I set the django module to the python3 path?

Please answer these 2 questions. I'm a newbie so please bear with me lol.

This is my path from python..

```
naveed@naveed-VirtualBox:~$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 21:31:18) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path

['', '/usr/lib/python3.2', '/usr/lib/python3.2/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Comment: Did you read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/? which part are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip` to install Django. [`pip`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial) is used to install python packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

Since you are using Python3, install pip by running:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Once pip gets installed, you can install the latest version of Django for Python 3 by running:

```
pip3 install django
```

Thereafter, you can verify that it installed successfully by importing it in your Python 3 interpreter:

```
>>> import django
>>> print(django.getversion())
1.6.2    # Latest version as of today
```

---

You don't need to worry about installing Django to your path.. `pip` would take care of all those stuff for you.